# Importing textual data removes some letters

Tags: import, text

I have the following file TSV file `p.txt` containing a single line of 3 values:

`"22p"  "22o"   "22u"`

(The actual files are many lines, i.e. 2D, but I'm sticking to this minimum example)

Using either `Import["p.txt", "TSV"]` or `Import["p.txt", "Table"]` produces the same unintended output of:

`{{22, "22o", "22u"}}`

I.e. the first entry is falsely interpreted as a value and the letter "p" is removed. I would like to have every entry interpreted as a string. How to achieve this?

I know how to do it using the `ReadList` command. But I probably cannot use it as [I rely on the `CharacterEncoding->"Unicode"` option of `Import` for the data files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261507/27818). If there is another way to resepct the files Byte Encoding, I could also use `ReadList`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable automatic conversion to numbers:

```
Import["p.txt", "Table", "Numeric" -> False]

(* {{"22p", "22o", "22u"}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks again. I wish some of those things were documented better. But probably impossible looking at the huge number of options present in Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) is a very general function, and you have to look into the documentation of the format, such as [``"Table"``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html).